# Changing dashboardHeader font color in shiny and keep logo

Tags: html, css, shiny, shinydashboard

I have the following code for mi UI:

```
    header <- dashboardHeader()

anchor <- tags$a(href='https://www.lssu.edu/cfre/',
                 tags$img(src='logo12.png', height='40', width='40'),
               'MiWaterNet')
#anchor$children[[2]]$children <-tags$div(
#  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("h1 { color: red}"))),class='name')
header$children[[2]]$children <- tags$div(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".name {background-color: transparent}"))),
  anchor,
  class = 'name')


dashboardPage( 
  title="CFRE MiWaterNet",
skin="black",
header,
dashboardSidebar(disable = T),
dashboardBody()
```

which gives this as a result:
[resulting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARJRY.png)

I want to be able to change the font (MiWaterNet) to yellow while keeping the logo as is. I have checked other questions, but those answers won't really fit with the way I structured the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add style as shown below:

```
header <- dashboardHeader()

anchor <- tags$a(href='https://www.lssu.edu/cfre/',
                 tags$img(src='YBS.png', height='40', width='40'),
                 'MiWaterNet', style = "color:red;")
#anchor$children[[2]]$children <-tags$div(
#  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("h1 { color: red}"))),class='name')
header$children[[2]]$children <- tags$div(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".name {background-color: transparent}"))),
  anchor,
  class = 'name')


ui <- dashboardPage( 
  title="CFRE MiWaterNet",
  skin="black",
  header,
  dashboardSidebar(disable = T),
  dashboardBody()
)
  
server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]